# How to prevent a troll from exploiting my validation to annoy people?

Tags: exploit, validation

My app has a demo mode where you can request a login to use the site in an unlimited way for a specific amount of time (15 days). At this point, the visitor is anonymous and we have no identifying information about them.

To prevent people from signing up for lots of free accounts, and never buying, we send a verification code via email or SMS, the idea being that we can keep track of previously sent codes and prevent duplicates. (Someone could get multiple email addresses, but at least it's a hindrance to abuse.)

But what if a malicious user doesn't care about the demo, and just wants to annoy people by entering their phone number and causing my system to send them texts? What can be done to stop this (without breaking the experience for legitimate users)?

Comment: Does your SMS verification process cost money?

Comment: @user2320464: no. If it did, most people wouldn't use it, I think.

Comment: Does it cost *you* money? @JoshuaFrank

Comment: No. I just don't want people getting annoying messages from a service with our name, because it would make us look bad.